# How to create CSR, P12 file as the same way "Certificate Assistant.app" using OpenSSL

Tags: security, ssl, https, apple-push-notifications, pkix

**Question:**
I would like to know what options are required to create `CSR(.certSigningRequest)` and export `P12` files as the same with "Certificate Assistant.app" does.

I use this `CSR` and `P12` files for Apple Push Service.

This is what I do:
1. [Certificate Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQfz4.png)
2. [Key Pair Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQJtH.png)
3. Upload `CSR` on Apple Developer Program site and downlaod `CER` file.
4. Open `CER` file and [this is what I see on "Keychain Access"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz4e5.png).
5. Export `certificate` and `private key` as `apn-cert.p12` and `apn-key.p12` on "Keychain Access".

Now I am trying to automate these operations.
I googled and tried the following `openssl` command but can not same result with above steps. `private key` does not appear on "Keychain Access".

> $ openssl genrsa -out private.key 2048
>   $ openssl req -new -key private.key
>   -out server.csr -subj "/emailAddress=foobar@example.com, CN=MyAppNameHere, C=JP"

I would like solution using `OpenSSL` command for best.
If `fastlane/pem` can solve this, I welcome some hints.

Thanks.

.

*My background reason of this question:*
I work as Agent of Apple Developer Enterprise Program on my office.
I have reasons that I do not let developers to join as Admin/Member to team.

I get requests from developers and I manually create Certificates on Apple Developer Program site.

I would like to automate this job because I am Programmer :)
For now I wrote python script using `Selenium` and `ATOMac` library and automate these but so dirty and poor for maintenance.

Comment: Have you heard about certifire.io?

Comment: @arturdev nop. let me check about it. thanks!

Comment: let me know if you'll have any question

Comment: @arturdev I checked certifire.io . I do almost hundreds of this operation yearly and certfire.io seem took too much  cost for my case.  let me consider different solution. thanks.

Comment: And how much are you willing to pay for that?